# Get all the users from multi-tenant AD Application using graph API

Tags: azure, active-directory, multi-tenant, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the users for a multi-tenant application using the graph API. For the purpose, I generated the access token using the request:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

**Note:** Please note that, in above request, I used `common` in place of `{tenantID}`. That was just a hit and try as the same was suggested for adminConsent in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0#3-get-administrator-consent).

By using the above generated access token, I requested the user API and got the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
        "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "56141b7d-dd5e-44b1-9395-cd15d02b52de",
            "date": "2019-06-17T12:42:19"
        }
    }
}
```

And when I generate the token using tenant ID, it only returns the users of one active directory.

Can anyone suggest, where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using common endpoint, you can not use client credentials flow(get access without user) here. You need to refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0)(get access on behalf of a user) .

**Note:** When you use auth code grant flow(get access on behalf of a user), you need to grant **delegated permission** instead of application permission.

[image]

get access token

[image]

Comment: I used the above-provided method but still not able to get the users of second active directory. But if the user from second active directory tries to log-in to my application, he/she is allowed to do so.

Comment: @mohitsharma If you don't have User.Read.All in your token, you need to identity your scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All`

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I was waiting for the admin consent to be provided by other tenant admin. After that, Tried but the response was still the same. I decoded the Toke and the `scp` was like `"scp": "Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All IdentityProvider.Read.All Mail.Read profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All openid email"`

Comment: I didn't get any error, it simply returns the users on one AD.

Comment: @mohitsharma Yes, this is the expected result. Are you going to get the users from all the AD tenants which grant admin consent?

Comment: Yes, I want users from all the AD tenants.

Comment: @mohitsharma This is not possible. Your application will know the tenant information only when you login. If user A from A tenant signed in, you can only get the users from A tenant.

Comment: @mohitsharma The token is is always tenant-specific.

Answer (score 1):

In a Multi-tenant Application, Service principal objects are created in each tenant which access the application. These service principal objects will hold the consent (user/admin) objects which are specific to that tenant and the secret is linked to these objects as well.

So when you get a token, it is always tenant-specific and you need to get separate tokens for each tenant to perform any operation in that tenant.

Example: Consider you have a multi-tenant application registered in tenant A and is also being used by tenants B, C and D. This will create SP objects in tenants B, C, and D as well.

So if you need to perform any operation in tenant B, you need a token for the SP B and use the secret linked to it.

In short, you need creds from all the tenants if you want to perform these operations in the context of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to implement this, was successful in that. These are the steps I had done.

1. Created a multi-tenant application
2. Gave Application permissions
3. Configure the GraphClient with a tenant-specific auth header.

Here is the code to get the tenant-specific graph client.

```
private ClientCredentialProvider GetGraphAuthProvider(Guid tenantId) {
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"])
                .WithTenantId(Convert.ToString(tenantId))
                .WithClientSecret(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
                .Build();
            return new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
        }

        public GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(Guid tenantId) = >new GraphServiceClient(GetGraphAuthProvider(tenantId));
    }
}
```

I have explained everything in [my blog here](https://sibeeshpassion.com/get-users-from-different-tenants-using-azure-ad-application-permission/).

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to get an app-level access token using the *"common"* and you are not specifying the tenant id anywhere in your request. You could either specify the tenant id in the url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token` or you could specify it within the request body. In that case, your request should look like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={client Id}
&scope={scopes, in your case ".default"}
&client_secret={client secret}
&tenant_id={organization's tenant id}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```