# Get AzureAd users of specific tenant for Multi tenant .net-core web app

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a multi tenant app registered on Azure Ad, and each time a user logs in I want to get all the users of the organization. I configured the app in my code and on Azure

[My .net-core app with azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih0Gt.png) and
[ms graph authorizations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2NnA.png)

So when someone logs in it asks for "read" permissions. Now I want to get all users of a specific tenant, I tried first on Postman
[to get the access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZMF4.png) and
[get users with the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zKaL.png)
it worked for this tenant because it is the app owner on Azure, but when I try with another tenant which is using my app, it doesn't work.
[I got the access token for another tenant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Pd5.png) and then
[I have an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOWSE.png)
I'm a little bit confused, is it the right way to do that or did I miss something ?

EDIT : It works if someone of the other tenant [grant admin consent here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuHHN.png) on Azure Ad, it adds Application Permissions but I don't want to do it on Azure but on the App

Comment: check required permissions for this graph api endpoint from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: I already added them on Azure and "User.Read,User.Read.All,User.ReadBasic.All" in my app

Comment: Include directory permissions as well

Comment: I added Directory.Read.All Delegated and Application on Azure, and in my app but nothing changed

Comment: are you trying to get all users from both tenant based on client credentials? which won't work. It should be token on behalf of user which will also returns uses of specific tenant.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632162/get-all-the-users-from-multi-tenant-ad-application-using-graph-api

Comment: I want to get all users from the tenant of the user who logged in only

Comment: then authentication code flow should be used on behalf of user to get that users list from graph api. please check above stackoverflow link for the process.

Comment: I'm doing this thing in my app, it redirects to /authorize but there are only delegated permissions : scope=openid profile offline_access User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All, application permissions are missing. Also, do I need to get the authorization code in my code ?

Comment: on behalf user auth code flow, delegated permissions should be enough. For client credentails it required application permissions additionally.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, so I had an error in my code, I followed this link https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md but now when I want to get an access token with _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync I have this error :

Comment: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition: Error: False MSAL 4.42.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.3, Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException
, ErrorCode: user_null
HTTP StatusCode 0
CorrelationId  // Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException' IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.

Comment: as the error states, your user object/user tenant is null when passing as input to acquiring token. please check User Account details post login from either Graph API or HTTPContext.

Comment: I have a User in my HttpContext, with an Identity and claims but I had to add them manually because claims in the security token were not added to the HttpContext, (I don't know why, I have a Google Authentication too and it worked fine) . The tenant given to the GetAccessTokenForUser method is correct.

Comment: After researches, my user in HttpContext does not contain everything I need,: the methods GetMsalAccountId() GetNameIdentifierId and GetHomeTenantId return null, how can I change this ?